# Grid View with UIPageControl in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, gridview, dynamic, uipagecontrol

I know there are plenty of Grid Views out there for iOS and Objective-c, but I couldn't find one that fits me. Currently I use a grid view called `UIGridView`. It included only two files and was very simple to implement. However it cannot have more cells than it can fit on the screen. I want a dynamic grid view where I can have a `UIPageControl` to have multiple pages with cells. I like the `UITableView` but for this project it would be more efficient to have a grid view.

I currently use this grid view: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/380/Interactive+Grid+View/

Is there a simple grid view with page control? Or can I put my current grid view in in a `UIPageControl`?

Comment: Have you taken a look over there at CocoaControls?

Comment: How about subclassing UIScrollView? That should be fairly simple.

Comment: Yeah every day ;) Gone over the controls there and can't find what I'm looking for @Cyrille

Comment: @Jacos just set self.pagingEnabled = YES and an appropriate content size.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think he's looking for "clean" methods like the reusable cells of `UITableView`, but on a grid. Hmmm, iOS 6, hear me coming...

Comment: @Cyrille I'm currently planning to write a 2D UITableView clone... but wait, isn't a scroll view clean enough (whatever it is meant to signify...)?

Comment: @H2CO3 - Already done it at work for my part, but no way to share it. By "clean" I mean something that recycle its views and does not load more cells than visible.

Comment: @Cyrille I know... and why no way to share it? Don't you know how to use Git? (rant)

Comment: There are plenty of things I currently do at work I'd love to share, alas I'm bound by my contract. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I settled with the MMGridView. It has horizontal page control scrolling. I just modified the cells to my liking. You can find the git source here: https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `CHGridView` at https://github.com/camh/CHGridView ?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using **`AQGridView`** so surely i recommend that as it is the least buggy and its functions are very similar to `UITableView`.

Also that If you are trying to do this without **XIB** it will be little bit difficult for you to handle it but you can create a view controller with Xib file to Create the interface of your choice. [Here is the Video of how it can be done in the best possible way](http://vimeo.com/46408155) by  `Evadne Wu`. And [here](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) is the Sample Project

**Now for the Paging Control**
in AQGridView you just need to set Paging Enabled and it will automatically do the rest. Hope that helps.